# JavaScript RegExp Custom URL validation with ${protocol}

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having some difficulty getting my regular expressions to pass.  My expression is supposed to validate a url. For the protocol, it will allow three values: http, https, and ${protocol}.

So, here are some examples of VALID urls:

- http://someurl.com
- https://someurl.com
- ${protocol}://someurl.com

So far, the first two pass with my current RegExp, but the ${protocol} ones won't pass.  Can some one please try to help me debug this and see why my ${protocol} isn't passing?

**Here is my RegExp so far:**

```
var urlRegEx = new RegExp('(\$\{protocol\}|http(s)?)://(([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+))+((/?)(([A-Za-z0-9\._\-]+)(/){0,1}[A-Za-z0-9.-/]*)){0,1}', 'i');
```

Comment: when using `RegExp` you have to write all backslashes twice: `(\\$\\{protocol` etc.

Comment: @thg435 Make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when using `RegExp` you have to write all backslashes twice: `(\\$\\{protocol` etc.

(from [thg435](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/thg435)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902546/javascript-regexp-custom-url-validation-with-protocol#comment29610532_19902546))